# Rails 4.2 not loading correct image

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on the [depot_a app](https://pragprog.com/titles/rails4/source_code) from [Agile Web Development with Rails 4](https://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails-4). Following the steps in Task A, all images are in `app/assets/images/`:

```
[~/projects/try_ruby/depot]$ ls app/assets/images/
cs.jpg  logo.png  rails.png  rtp.jpg  ruby.jpg
```

In `app/views/products/index.html.erb`, the code to present the image:

`<%= image_tag(product.image_url, class: 'list_image') %>`

Instead of accessing `asset/cs.jpg`, it actually generates the obfusticated image path (see the screenshot): `/assets/cs-436e7e2d621d24ea1d19769362306ecdec83fcd62d5d45f135adca63e6a0f9c5.jpg`.

Why is that?

[image: Not loading the correct image assets]

The jpg contains error:

[image: The erroneous jpg]

EDIT:

My rails version is 4.2. But the book's depot app is based on Rails 4.0. So I downgraded Rails to 4.0 and re-did the steps again (regenerated scaffold, db seeding, etc.), then the jpg photos are shown correctly. It seems like a version thing. But I still don't know why jpg doesn't load in Rails 4.2.

Comment: You are not accessing the `/assets/images/` path at all. The problem is what the path stored in your `Product` model.

Comment: Could you show us, how did you save the image_path?

Comment: The `Product`'s image_url is always is the image name, like `cs.jpg`. I tried it in rails console. Executing `image_tag(product.image_url)` will generate something like: `<img src="/images/cs.jpg" alt="Cs" />`

Comment: Do you running in production or development mode?

Answer (score 0):

The obfusticated image path `/assets/cs-436e7e2d621d24ea1d19769362306ecdec83fcd62d5d45f135adca63e6a0f9c5.jpg.` could be from the `public/assets` directory and not `app/assets directory`. The possible reason is that you precompiled your assets.

Comment: I don't think I enabled the precompile options in `application.rb` or `development.rb`.